# Export SQL query to JSON formatted text file

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I need a way to run a SQL command and then export the results to a JSON formatted text file.

I have this link: https://falseisnotnull.wordpress.com/2014/11/23/creating-json-documents-with-mariadb/

But I don't understand the CREATE_COLUMN section of his statement, nor really the terminology he uses to understand how it relates to my DB.

Can anyone please simplify his example for me on a query like this?

```
SELECT * FROM thisismy.database;
```

If I do the above with the INTO OUTFILE command, I get data that looks like this:

```
1     Armand         Warren   56045   Taiwan, Province of China   0        0
2      Xenos    Salas        71090        Liberia        0                0
3      Virginia   Whitaker   62723   Nicaragua   0                       0
4      Kato Patrick   97662   Palau   0                       0
5      Cameron      Ortiz P9C5B6   Eritrea 0                0
```

But I need it to look like this:

```
{ "aaData": [
    [ "1", "Armand", "Warren", "56045", "Taiwan, Province of China" ],
    [ "2", "Xenos", "Salas", "71090", "Liberia" ],
    [ "3", "Virginia", "Whitaker", "62723", "Nicaragua" ],
    [ "4", "Kato", "Patrick", "97662", "Palau" ],
    [ "5", "Cameron", "Ortiz", "P9C 5B6", "Eritrea" ]
] }
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Edit:  I run MariaDB if that helps

Comment: See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/connect-json-table-type/

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CONCAT('[\n\t', GROUP_CONCAT(
        COLUMN_JSON(
            COLUMN_ADD(
                COLUMN_CREATE('id', id)
                , 'name', name
                , 'price', price
            )
        )
        ORDER BY id
        SEPARATOR ',\n\t'
    ), '\n]') AS json
    FROM product \G
```

Ignore everything except `COLUMN_CREATE`. This is where the JSON creation is happening. OK, so we have:

```
COLUMN_JSON(
        COLUMN_ADD(
            COLUMN_CREATE('id', id)
            , 'name', name
            , 'price', price
        )
    )
```

`COLUMN_ADD` is the function that adds the columns to the JSON. Each argument is a key paired with its value. So `'name'` is what the key in the JSON object will be and `name` is what the value will be. In this case it's the column `name` from the table `product`.

So, let's say you want to query your `users` table and get their first names, last names, and ID. This is what your query would look like:

```
SELECT CONCAT('[\n\t', GROUP_CONCAT(
        COLUMN_JSON(
            COLUMN_ADD(
                COLUMN_CREATE('id', id)
                , 'first_name', first_name
                , 'last_name', last_name
            )
        )
        ORDER BY id
        SEPARATOR ',\n\t'
    ), '\n]') AS json
    FROM users \G
```

And at the end of the `COLUMN_JSON` command we have `AS json`, which casts it as the JSON type you want.

Comment: Thank you, but I get an error with that code.  Here is a clearer example of what I have used:   https://pastebin.com/FEFvvaXm

Comment: You need to select from a table, not a database.

Comment: Still not working.  Name of my DB (changed for privacy reasons) is 'cubesat' and the name of my table is 'places'.  All my data is stored in this 'places' table.  So with your command, I do FROM cubesat.places to specify the DB/table name.  It won't work if I just specify the table without the DB name - nor with any variation of db / table name.   Updated Pastebin:  https://pastebin.com/yi9j76TG

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY mimetype_file1
    SEPARATOR ',\n\t'
  ), '\n]') AS json
  FROM dbname' at line 8

Comment: Line 8 is the ORDER BY portion

Comment: @user7433145 Sorry, I went to bed before you replied. I'm not sure what the problem is, but try ordering by `id` instead. Do all rows have a `mimetype_file1` value?

Comment: Also just try removing the ORDER BY section and see if it works that way. I don't really see why you would get a syntax error for my previous comment...

Answer (score 0):

You can use sql2json(I created the python package).

```
python3 -m sql2json --name mysql --query "SELECT a, b from my_table" --wrapper --output myoutputfile.json
```

You will get:

```
{
    data: [
        {
            "a": 1,
            "b": 5
        },
        {
            "a": 2,
            "b": 10
        }
    ]
}
```

sql2json is free and hosted in github: https://github.com/fsistemas/sql2json