# Export MySQL dump in plain text file to JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json, ssh

I need to export a 1GB file from a MySQL dump in a plain text file on my web server to a JSON file. How can I do this using PHP– from SSH?

I looked around and found no similar questions that could answer or help me. I have looked as much as I could find on the Internet about this and for almost a week and that's why I decided to submit this question.

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: ??? A .sql file is a plain text file. Just give a .txt extension if you wish

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?
Convert SQL to JSON?

Comment: It is a MySQL dump, has .sql extension...

Comment: @ThisBoyPerforms Yeah, a .sql file containing a MySQL dump. I'll run the script in SSH, but it is a masive file (1GB)

Comment: @KevinAndrews
How did you get the SQL file?
If you can, redo the export and export directly to JSON.

Comment: *"I have looked the whole internet for almost a week"* - I've been on the web since 1995 and I've yet to go through the entire Internet. You should rephrase your question.

Comment: @ThisBoyPerforms Downloded a mysql database dump, I need to make it json . So cant dump it again with `mysqldump`

Comment: @Fred-ii- An expresion, don't be literal. I've added *italic*

Comment: I edited your question, I think that better represents itself ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks , can you tell me the answer then for my issue :)

Comment: welcome. Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/q/5036605/ and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-admin-export-import.html and https://stackoverflow.com/q/45364453/ ? to name a few. And, from you found, did you try anything and that may have failed somehow?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I did, none what I'm looking for. I'm looking for to convert Plain text files .sql to json, with PHP.

Comment: http://www.kodingmadesimple.com/2015/01/convert-mysql-to-json-using-php.html  I don't know what else to look for here. See the answer below. I can't help you anymore, wish I could sorry.

Answer (score 0):

`phpMyAdmin` lets you export in JSON format